# C# program calling to directory on my (developer) computer when running on other's

Tags: c#

So I've just made my first C# program on Visual Studio. I then copied everything from the release folder (including 1 .exe file, dll files, 1 config file and 1 pdb file) then sent it to another computer. The problem here is that the exe file works fine on my computer, but on the others they crash when it run the first command that requires the dll file, and on the error message that I catch it says that problem is on line xx of "my computer's path to the file", even though it's running on the other's.

Source code of where the crash happens:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter file path (Example: C:\\Benchmarking.xlsx)");
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
FileInfo xlFile = new FileInfo(@fileName);
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(xlFile);
```

Error: System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is using EPPLUS to read excel files

Comment: The line number of the source file is not relevant to solving the problem, it's only shown to aid in debugging. Read the error text and solve it.

Comment: Add your source code

Comment: The source code is on the machine where you built the executable. It's not on the machine where the executable is running. To find the source code, you must go to the machine where the source code is located.

Comment: I've added the source code

Comment: That code does not throw that exception. Add the stack trace as well and try searching the web on that exception message.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a debug build which includes .PDB files.  PDB files point to the paths on the machine on which the code was compiled.  When an exception is thrown, you'll see the old paths.